# ul list of expanders doesnt act as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create expander similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp). I mean when user click `Section xx` this should expand to bottom. for now when user clicks it looks like:

[image]

but I want it be like:
[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khb0dt28/)

here js:

```
 let sectionIndex = 0;

    function addSection(position, relation) {
      const template = `
    <li class="section">
      <button aria-label="Add section above" class="section__button section__button--up" value="beforebegin">&#8593;</button>
      <button aria-label="Add section below" class="section__button section__button--down" value="afterend">&#8595;</button>
      <span class="section__label collapsible"><button class="collapsible">Section ${++sectionIndex}</button> 
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
              ea
              commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
      </span>     
    </li>`;
      relation.insertAdjacentHTML(position, template);

    }

    const sections = document.querySelector('.js-sections');
    sections.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      const button = event.target.closest('.section__button');
      if (button !== null) {
        const position = button.value;
        const relation = button.parentElement;
        addSection(position, relation);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Basically I have removed the flex properties in .section__label class. This was what was causing the elements to be next to each other, you could also try changing the flex-direction to column if you still need flex.

And I added a new class .section__label button { display:block; width: 100%; } just to match your desired style a bit more.

You still need to work on your border styling and sizing of the parent container. But this is a start for you.

```html
<style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .section {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 3em 3em;
      grid-template-columns: 3em 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:
        "up label"
        "down label";
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 0.5em 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .section__button {
      appearance: none;
      background-color: #d8d8d8;
      font-size: 1em;
      border: 0;
      padding: 1em;
      margin: 0;
      color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
      ;
    }

    .section__button:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    .section:hover .section__button {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .section__button--up {
      grid-area: up;
    }

    .section:hover .section__button--up {
      background-color: #215467;
    }

    .section__button--down {
      grid-area: down;
    }

    .section:hover .section__button--down {
      background-color: #e2a418;
    }

    .section:hover .section__button:hover {
      background-color: #55c773;
    }

    .section__label {
      grid-area: label;
      padding: 2em 5em 2em 2em;
    }
    
    .section__label button {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    /*collapsible*/
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      grid-column: 2;
    }

    .collapsible {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .collapsible>button {
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="js-sections">
    <li>
      <div class="section">
        <button aria-label="Add section above" class="section__button section__button--up "
          value="beforebegin">&#8593;</button>
        <button aria-label="Add section below" class="section__button section__button--down "
          value="afterend">&#8595;</button>
        <span class="section__label collapsible"><button class="collapsible">Section 0
          </button>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
              ea
              commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let sectionIndex = 0;

    function addSection(position, relation) {
      const template = `
    <li class="section">
      <button aria-label="Add section above" class="section__button section__button--up" value="beforebegin">&#8593;</button>
      <button aria-label="Add section below" class="section__button section__button--down" value="afterend">&#8595;</button>
      <span class="section__label collapsible"><button class="collapsible">Section ${++sectionIndex}</button> 
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
              ea
              commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
      </span>     
    </li>`;
      relation.insertAdjacentHTML(position, template);

    }

    const sections = document.querySelector('.js-sections');
    sections.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      const button = event.target.closest('.section__button');
      if (button !== null) {
        const position = button.value;
        const relation = button.parentElement;
        addSection(position, relation);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: some of the paragraph is hidden